# Push notification with React Native + Expo + Back4app

Tags: react-native, expo, back4app

how can I integrate push notifications with React Native + Expo + Back4app

Comment: Which kind of notification you're looking for?  Cloud or Local Notification?

Comment: My problem is that the React Native guide of Back4app does not explain with project with expo and in the part of modifying the androidmanifest.xml it does not exist I would like to know both local and in the cloud. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Back4App has it own push notification system but its not recommended to use it for expo because there are additional configurations you need to work on. read https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/why-not-expo/ for more details.

However, it is quite easy to trigger push notifications in Expo. https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/ . If you look at the diagram here, you can have a cloud code setup that will do a post request to the Expo backend to trigger the push notification.